# What does *exactly* happen during a try catch operation?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

> Feel free to skip straight to [TL/DR](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51408832) if you're not interested in details of the question

---

### A brief preamble:

I recently decided to fully re-learn JavaScript from the ground up.
This time not only how it works, but also why it works. Everything makes much more sense once you learn also how the compiler works and all the other nitty gritty details, issue is there's this one small pre-built expression:

[`try.. catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

And I can't quite wrap my head around as to why it works, **when it seems to go against all the lexing and scope rules that JS has in place.**

---

### The things I don't get:

Shouldn't it break the scope?

Here we are working only with 2 levels of scope.
The scope inside `try{ }` the scope inside `catch{ }` and the `global` scope. If we were to illustrate this, it would look something like this:

[image]

Now the two inner scopes should act as the two individual scopes and not conflict with each other. With that in mind, **how come that the value of `try {}` gets returned to the `catch {}` block, when it should be enclosed within itself as a scope.

I even tried using `"use strict";` to see if I could somehow catch an Exception of trying to pass argument outside of block scope, but even then.. nada, works just as expected:

> <sub>*Technically I created an extra scope here with the `function()`,
>   unfortunately it's impossible to use strict mode in jsfiddle without
>   self-invoked function*</sub>

```js
(function(){
"use strict";

 try {
          throw 'MadeUpError';
 }

 catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
 }

})();
```

**How come the `try {}` block is able to pass an argument to the `catch {}` block, despite the fact it is conflicting with the `strict mode`?**

Seems pretty illogical, when the identifier `(e)` should be unique only to it's own scope.

Furthermore, I can't even seem to make sense of it lexically. 
The catch blocks calls for a Right Hand Side Lookup of a nonexistent index(?) of the thrown Exception.
**From where and how does it know where from should it retrieve the Exception**?

---

### TL/DR:

Probably the easiest way to answer this question would be to answer it in a pseudo-language of a compiler: eg.

```
/*
    1. I arrived at try { } block
    2. Created a new Exception
    3. I stored Exception at (?)
    4. Exited try { }
    5. I looked up Exception from ...
*/
```

Hopefully you get my longwinded post. I know this is more of a theoretical question, but I want to fully comprehend **what is happening behind the scenes during the `try..catch` operation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I arrive at the `try {` block and push its location onto a stack of `try {` blocks (will be popped out when the `}` is reached)*
- I execute the code inside the block
- I arrive at a `throw whatever`
- I evaluate the `whatever` as an expression (if it is an identifier i look it up in the current scope)
- I stored the result of the evaluation in a temporary internal variable
- I look up the upmost `try { }` from the stack and pop it
- I go to the related `catch(identifier) { }` block
- I create the `identifier` in the scope of the catch block, and copy the value of the internal variable to it
- I execute the catch block
- I execute the code after the catch block

(Thats very simplified and it even gets a bit more complicated inside of an `async` function), you can read the whole story at $13.15.7/8 of the ECMA spec.

> Shouldn't it break the scope?

The thrown thing doesn't have to be part of `try { }`s scope at all:

```
throw new Error();
```

It can also be only part of the expression. If it is however part of the scope as:

```
const error = new Error();
throw error; // <- handed over to some internal engine logic
```

Then throwing it will cause it to be copied out of the scope (into some internal variable), the scope will stop existing (as the block stops executing) and it will be copied into a new variable of a new scope:

```
catch(err) { // <- the error suddenly appears from inside the engine here
```

So there will be two scopes with two variables, but they hold the same value.

---

*The Spec defines it as a recursive evaluation of blocks, which will then wind up at the `throw` statement until it reaches a Try block, but I think its easier to understand with a stack (which recursion will be at the end).

Comment: @rawrplus glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

(function(){

```
"use strict";

    try {
          throw 'MadeUpError';
    }

    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

})();
```

> How come the try {} block is able to pass an argument to the catch {}
>   block, despite the fact it is conflicting with the strict mode?

Think of this like a sort of if/else block. IF there is an Error THEN execute what's in the catch block. The "e" (Error object) is automatically included in the catch block, because of course you'd want to know what the error was. Javscript is simply putting it on the stack and allowing you to reference it automatically